# Convert String to Joda LocalTime format (HH:mm:ss) and Remove milliseconds

Tags: java, jodatime

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
LocalTime localTime = fmt.parseLocalTime("02:51:20");
System.out.println("LocalTime:            "+localTime);
```

I need only 02:51:20 but it outputs as 02:51:20.000. Is there any way that I can remove the .000 (milliseconds) from the output?

Comment: Well, just reuse your formatter for printing instead of parsing

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer and it works. Is there a way that I can get that in LocalTime instead of String. I need LocalTime as 02:51:20 and not 02:51:20.000.

Comment: No, the `.toString()` of `LocalTime` is fixed. You need to go through a formatter to have the format you want.

Comment: Ok. How to remove the milliseconds from the LocalTime. I need LocalTime only HH:mm:ss format and not the milliseconds included. Is it possible ?

Comment: Hold on, I thought you said the provided solutions worked?

Comment: Yes I do, when I print it removes the .000 from the localtime. But i need the response in LocalTime in the format HH:mm:ss without the milliseconds in it. Am trying to format a String of the format HH:mm:ss to LocalTime without milliseconds. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you just need to format when you print out. Currently you're just using the default `toString()` representation. If you're happy with the formatter you've already got, you can just use:

```
System.out.println("LocalTime:            " + fmt.print(localTime));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use your `DateTimeFormetter print() method`. Try like this;

```
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    LocalTime localTime = fmt.parseLocalTime("02:51:20");
    System.out.println("LocalTime                        :  " + localTime);
    System.out.println("LocalTime with DateTimeFormatter :  " + fmt.print(localTime));
```

And the output is;

```
LocalTime                        :  02:51:20.000
LocalTime with DateTimeFormatter :  02:51:20
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this using

```
DateTime time = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String localTime = time != null ? format.print(new LocalTime(time.getHourOfDay(), 
time.getMinuteOfHour(), time.getSecondOfMinute())) : null;
```

DateTime and LocalTime are from joda