# Formatting Joda Time LocalDate to MMddyyyy

Tags: java, jodatime

I am attempting to format a desired joda time LocalDate type to a mmddyyy format and I am running into trouble and not sure how to proceed. I've tried a couple different things so far and had no luck.

So I pretty much want to take a date like 04-15-2016 and get a LocalDate type from it in format, 04152016, but it still needs to be in the LocalDate format, not a string.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMddyyyy");
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.parse("04152016", dtf);
System.out.println(currentDate);
```

The date comes out as 2016-04-15. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. Perhaps I am missing something fundamental when it comes to the Joda Time library.

THank you.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you use your `DateTimeFormatter` to format the `currentDate`?

Comment: You need to understand that a `LocalDate` doesn't have a format - that's not part of its state. When you want to convert it to text in a particular form, you use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Your currentDate represents a moment in time. You can print that moment out in a way that the French would understand, or someone in India, for example.

Please start by taking a look at the [Joda documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Formatters). In particular, see the entry

```
String b = dt.toString("dd:MM:yy");
```

You could adapt it by printing

```
currentTime.toString("MMddyyyy");
```

Or you could reuse your formatter and adopt [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989550/509840) (cited in the comments).

```
System.out.println(dtf.print(currentDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Data types like `long`, `double`, `Date` and `LocalDate` are values and don't store your preferred format for how you want to display them.

When you want to display them a particular way, you need to use a formatter to turn them into a String, then the String has a format, but the value never does (other than it's default format built in)

Comment: If you also show how to do it, you'd get my +1.

Comment: @Andreas show which in particular?

Comment: Show how print the LocalDate in the desired format, e.g. `System.out.println(dtf.print(currentDate));`

Comment: @Andreas I would see rajah9's answer.